# Fonts won't render in production rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I feel like I've tried every combination and I can't get fonts to render properly in development and production. The following works great in development:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'hamilton19';
  src: font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.eot');
  src: font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
   font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
  src: font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

With the font files being in a fonts directory inside of assets. But doesn't work in production.

I also have:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

inside of application.rb

And I run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

before I deploy.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your fonts within the `stylesheets` controller (`assets/stylesheets/fonts/<font_files>`), and reference them like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'hamilton19';
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.eot');
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Also, you should remove the `config.assets.path` reference in your environment definitions

Comment: So I don't need the '/assets...' in front of the path? ANd keep the fonts directory inside of assets?

Comment: Nope - you should reference the fonts from the base assets dir :) I've literally just been sorting this out for one of our apps. You should put `/fonts` into `/assets/stylesheets`

Comment: So, throw all the fonts directly in /assets., I'm guessing remove the `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')` line, precompile on production, and deploy?

Comment: Thanks very much. Should I still `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?